# change element of multidimensional array php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've this multidimensional array and i need to change `type` field when i found `parc` value, in this case `100` in this array with php... but the all always i found replace total array by the last array. anyone can help me? thanks a lot... sorry for my bad english.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [designacao] => 
            [imagem] => 
            [produto] => KITCHENAID Robot de cozinha Artisan 5KSM150PSETG cor-de-laranja
            [preco_t] => 710
            [t_parc] => Parcela 1
            [parc] => 100
            [symbol] => €
            [zona] => COZINHA
            [id] => 0
            [type] => checkbox
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [designacao] => 
            [imagem] => 
            [produto] => KITCHENAID Robot de cozinha Artisan 5KSM150PSETG cor-de-laranja
            [preco_t] => 710
            [t_parc] => Parcela 2
            [parc] => 100
            [symbol] => €
            [zona] => COZINHA
            [id] => 0
            [type] => checkbox
        )
)
```

Comment: You need to change the 'type' field to what ? give an example of a change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 'parc' && $value == 100) {
        $array['type'] = 'something new';
    }
}
```

something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$source = array(); // your array

$keyName = 'parc';
$keyValue = 100;
$keyToChange = 'type';

array_walk($source, function (&$element) use ($keyName, $keyValue, $keyToChange) {
    if (
        array_key_exists($keyName, $element)
        && $element[$keyName] === $keyValue
    ) {
        $element[$keyToChange] = '[do_something]';
    }
});
```